# Recover overwritten external hard-drive

Tags: ubuntu, backup, external-hard-drive, overwrite

I had some data in my external hard drive (eHD), and performed a [dd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man1/dd.1.html) to backup my ubuntu filesystem onto the eHD.

I thought it would maintain the data that was previously there, plus the backup.

What i got:

I can only see the filesystem which i backed-up, and no signal of my previous data. However, when I see the portion of the eHD occupied, it shows as if the files are still there, that is, 
500 Gb of my old data, plus my filesystem which is 300 Gb. So in total I have 800 Gb of a 1 Tb disk occupied, so I'm guessing the data is somewhere, I just can't see it.

Any ideas on how to recover the data?

Comment: never, ever, EVER, run a dd command unless you know exactly what it's about to do.

Comment: I guess I understand why now. The fact that the disk occupied size shows as if it has the previous and the more recent backed-up files gives me some hope on their recovery. I'll try woliveirajr suggestions, hopefully they will work.

Comment: Do you know if it was 500GB on there before or 800GB before? Also, do you know the old format it was in? DD really isn't the best tool for making backups, rsync would work better. In the past, I've just copied and pasted partitions with gparted (which leads to identical UUIDs, but that can be fixed.)

Comment: I had 500 Gb in my eHD, after doing the dd I ended up with the a total of 800 Gb. Now I can only see these newer 300 Gb.  The format was NTFS.

Comment: Have you looked at with gparted? What does it show?

Comment: Just shows that its extension is now ext3 and that it has 800 Gb occupied

Comment: Where are you reading the 800gb usage?  My guess is that it is actually 500gb of data, but consuming 800gb due to block/sectors sizes.  You have overwritten the first (and presumably only) partition.  Can you post the results of the commands you are using?  ```df -h``` ```parted  /dev/sdc print```

Comment: Gparted gave me this output: http://imgur.com/FW5Oo               Your command output was this:                                     my@machine:~$ df -h parted /dev/sdb1 print                       df: `parted': No such file or directory
df: `print': No such file or directory
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sdb1             455G  330G  102G  77% /media/01ba465b-67dc-4644-98de-ca5770d5efc2

Answer (score 0):

That data is most likely nuked as you've overwritten it with the backup you performed. DD is a low-level copy facility; i.e it copies drives sector-by-sector. Any sectors it overwrote aren't coming back unless you get some forensic data recovery people in (and even then I doubt you'd get anything from it). Cut your losses as move on.

Is there anything that you absolutely NEED from that drive, though? You might want to try some of the drive recovery stuff in [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) as a last-ditch attempt to get at it, but there's no guarantees at all. (You'll probably want to use something like test-disk, but as I haven't had to do it for a while (thank god) it might be worth waiting for some else to suggest something.)

Comment: I can live without it, but there is work data I would like to recover. The fact that the disk usage shows what I backed-up plus another 500 Gb gave me some hope of recovering it.

Comment: What DD command did you use to do the backup? If by some miracle it preserved disk geometry (which it kind of sounds like it did), you have a good chance of getting it back.

Comment: dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1